# Python Selenium Chrome WebDriver Crashes on Camera/Mic Permissions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running into an issue where chromedriver crashes with no error or warnings as soon as I accept permissions for camera/audio within the tab that is generated.

**Sample Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://meet.jit.si/randomlink123321')
```

Steps to Repeat Failure:

1. Run code above
2. Click accept on Camera/Microphone pop-up
3. Note that the tab closes instantly

I would also in the future like to implement an auto-accept of permissions if possible. I attempted to use the Options class but was also unsuccessful as chromedriver kept closing instantly.

**Options code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 

  })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
driver.get('https://meet.jit.si/randomlink123321')
```

**ChromeDriver Version:**

```
(venv) ➜  pi git:(https-requests) ✗ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416})
```

Note: there are no errors or anything when this crash occurs

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem too. 
My solution was that I stopped running the program from the IDE (PyCharm for me) terminal.
I tried the standard OS terminal and everything was fine